# XSLT 2 not recognizing NULL value in TSV

Tags: xslt

I am parsing a TSV file and using only few column values.
If some of the column values are NULL, the XSLT is not recognizing them and counting the next column instead.

If I change the NULL value with some data, the XSLT is working fine.

Can someone help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="identifier"/>
<xsl:param name="csvData"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="csv" select="$csvData"/>
    <xsl:variable name="data">
    <data>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\n">
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <row>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\t" flags="x">
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <col>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                            </col>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </row>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </data>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:result-document>
    <Events>
        <xsl:for-each select="$data//row">
            <Attendance>
                <RetID><xsl:value-of select="../$identifier"/></RetID>
                <AccountId><xsl:value-of select="col[1]"/></AccountId>
                <EventId><xsl:value-of select="col[2]"/></EventId>
                <EventName><xsl:value-of select="col[3]"/></EventName>
                <EventDate><xsl:value-of select="col[4]"/></EventDate>
                <EventTime><xsl:value-of select="col[5]"/></EventTime>  
            </Attendance>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Events>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with your input files??

Comment: Please show us a sample of the tab separated input file format and explain exactly how null values are represented in that format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a "NULL" value in the tab separated data is indicated by two consecutive tab characters then I would suggest to replace

```
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\t" flags="x">
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <col>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                        </col>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
```

with

```
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\t')">
                        <col>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                        </col>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
```